# Can :environment be used as a condition in the route statement in sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, url-routing

Im trying to create a route that is only available for :development for example:

```
get '/logs', :environment => :development do
    #dump logs
end
```

This does not work, any ideas?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own condition to check the environment:

```
set(:check_env) {|value| condition{value == settings.environment}}

get '/logs', :check_env => :development do
  #dump logs
end
```

Another, possibly simpler, option would be to only create the route in development:

```
configure :development do
  get '/logs' do
    #dump logs
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get '/logs' if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
```

should work

Comment: also, `settings.environment` defaults to `ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym` so you can check if `settings.environment == :development`